# Existence of partial derivatives : $f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \text{ if } xy \neq 0\\ 1 \text{ if } xy=0 \end{cases} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would like to show that all the partial derivatives of $f: R^2 \rightarrow R$ defined by :

> $$f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \text{ if } xy \neq 0\\
> 1 \text{ if } xy=0
> \end{cases}
> $$

exist.
My attempt :

For this problem, we have several cases : $xy\neq0$ or $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$ or $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$ or $x=y=0$. If $xy \neq 0$, it is easy to see that the partial derivatives exist.

If $xy = 0$ :

There are $3$ different ways to approach $(0,0)$. So we have to check if the following limits exist : 
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(h,y)-f(0,y)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(h+x,0)-f(x,0)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(0,y+h)-f(0,y)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0,h\neq0}\frac{f(x,h)-f(x,0)}{h}$$

Is that correct ?

Comment: Technically yes, but better to phrase it pointwise - there are 4 categories of points: ($xy\neq 0$), ($x=0,y\neq 0$), ($y=0,x\neq 0$), ($x=y=0$), where the middle two are symmetric so you need only check one

Comment: But can we state that for all function ?